# Failed to Open Stream:No such file or directory in ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

Ok then. I have my connect.php file which recovers the infos about the server and the database from a txt file placed in my root folder. This one works since I can log into my portal and use almost all the features I've settle. The problem come everytime I have an AJAX call.
Everytime I try to use something that implies an AJAX call I get this Warning:

```
WARNING: FOPEN(CONFIG.TXT): FAILED TO OPEN STREAM: NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY.
```

Here's the connect code:

```
include_once ('installer.php');
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

$handle = fopen("config.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
   $i=0;
   while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
         $ln[$i]= trim($line);
         $i++;
   }
}
if (!$handle || $i == 0) {
    header("refresh:0;url=install.php");
    exit;
}
fclose($handle);

$db = mysql_connect($ln[0],$ln[1],$ln[2]);

if (!$db) {
   header("refresh:0;url=install.php");
   exit;
}
if (!mysql_select_db("jstool",$db))
   installdb();
```

which as I told before perfectly works almost everywhere in the portal.
Now if I don't include connect.php the ajax calls don't work. But if I do I get this warning and no data. Where's my problem?

Comment: is config.txt in the same patch as your script? has config.txt read permissions for the server user (www-data, apache, whatever)?

Comment: You mean config.php instead of connect.php? You config.php is in the root, where is this PHP file?

Comment: @putvande config.txt is where the infos are stored, connect.php is the script that I wrote up here. Both of them are in the same folder and config.txt has read permissions (by now I'm on my localhost with a XAMP)

Comment: By the way, why are you storing your DB credentials in a text file? That can cause some trouble.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with AJAX.

Comment: @CBroe this has everything to do with AJAX since the problem shows up only when I perform an AJAX call. The whole platform works with this.

Comment: @putvande they told me to stored them there.. what do you suggest for a more safe way to do it?

Comment: So if you make the exact same request directly from your browser’s address bar (or using another tool, assuming the request method might be POST), you get a _different_ result? That is hardly imaginable, especially since the code you have shown does not indicate that it relies on any request parameters. (And if you _don’t_ get a different result – then it _has_ nothing to do with AJAX.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem about relative path.

Where is this "config.txt" exactly inside your public_html?
Try to give it a path or relative path from your php which the ajax calls,and it will work.